# Scrapy - star_urls containing square brackets

Tags: python, url, scrapy, brackets

I'm trying to crawl a website and the star_urls contain square brackets `(?sec[3]=3)`

When I try to run the spider what happens is that the brackets are replaced by `%5B` and `%5D`.

I tried to use `ulrlib.unquote(url)` but the problem remains!

Here is my code:

```
import urllib as ul
...
urls = []

for sec in range(1, 20):
   url = "http://www.website.com/something?sec[%d]=%d" % (sec,sec)
   url = ul.unquote(url)
   urls.append(url)


start_urls = urls
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does it affect the crawling results?

Comment: Yes... nothing is retrieved because the urls don't exist.

Comment: Just do urllib.quote, or do nothing. It should work. Make sure this part of your code should be in global scope od spider class.

Comment: Initially I did nothing...and I got the issue. To use urllib.quote didn't work either :/